# HttpURLConnection- connect() throws Java ConnectException

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, httpurlconnection, connectexception

I use the code

```
public static int getResponseCode(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {         
    URL u = new URL(urlString);  
    HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
    huc.setRequestMethod("GET");
    huc.connect();
    return huc.getResponseCode();  
}
```

to get the Response code. When I run the code, I get an exception
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

I printed the URl which makes this error and then loaded it in browser. the link was loaded, but after some time, around 2 mins. What could be the reason why the status code is not returned? And How can I handle this case?

Thanks for your help!

Shari

Comment: can you post the error message ?

Comment: Yeah.. java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

Comment: can you post the url ?

Comment: http://quote2sales.com is the URL

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `huc.setReadTimeout(120000);` before `huc.connect()`.

However I am afraid that something is going wrong with your server side. Why does it replies after ~2 minutes?

Comment: Yeah, at times it loads too slow.

Comment: I just checked the same code for google.com and stuck with the same error for URL google.co.in/intl/en/options

Comment: Google.com works fine for me and takes less then 1 second. It seems that something is wrong with your internet connection.

Comment: yeh google.com loads but the above code throws that exception when the URL google.co.in/intl/en/options is passed to it

Comment: I'll disable my machine proxy and see :)

Comment: I got the same error...without proxy... The page loads fast but huc.connect(); has some issues

Answer (score 0):

You are saying that it took 2 minutes to load content in the browser. Most likely, you connection times out. You can try to [set a longer timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29) for your connection to 3 minutes in milliseconds

```
huc.setConnectTimeout(1800000);
```

If the issue is not timeout, then most likely you have to set the proxy for your connection. Check the proxy settings in your browser and set the appropriate values.  See, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320317/set-proxy-in-java), on how to do it.

Comment: I just checked the same code for http://google.com and stuck with the same error for URL http://www.google.co.in/intl/en/options/

Comment: Edited my answer with another suggestion

Comment: I have disabled the proxy but still gets this issue with some links. :(

Comment: That could be because of the company firewall if there is one and you go to outside links...